# How to know jQuery is loaded in a site?

Tags: jquery

I want to test a particular site. I wish the site has, jquery in it. But doing so in the console:

```
$
```

gives me `undefined`. But I can see they are using jQuery in `script` tag, like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Are there any other way I can access jQuery apart from `$`?

Comment: accessing jQuery by calling it with jQuery?! $ is only a short-hand

Comment: [This little tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-injector/indebdooekgjhkncmgbkeopjebofdoid) may be useful to you.

Comment: if jquery is present, why can't I call it using `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
It might be some  plugin may have overwritten the $ variable or 
You have JavaScript running before jquery is loaded .
```

Check your jquery path also and check with Firbug

or try with

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use $j instead of $ in your jquery code.

[More Info jquery conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 1):

try using it in this format :

```
jQuery(document).ready({ ....
```

instead of $

Also see if you can identify the jquery.js or check out this list. Here are various versions of jquery that might be available :

http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$`, use `$().jquery` which returns the version if jQuery is present.

Comment: Which is the version, used by the site you tested it on. Which means it is present, that was the point right?